# Maintain all cell alignments across adjacent table rows

Tags: html, css, html-email

In the three-column block below as I shrink the size of screen to adjust to mobile screens, the alignment between the header, the image and the text is no longer kept even though I have dictated fixed sizes for the table rows. How do I modify the code so that all three headlines, images and texts are correctly aligned? Is it because I am using separate tables?

[image]

```
<table border="0" valign="top" cellpadding="10" style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;background-color: #f99f11;">
<tr>
<td>
        <!-- Title: BEGIN-->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2>Ditt medlemskap</h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Title: END-->

        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #ffffff;" width="32%">
                            <table>

                                <tr height="10px" style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;">
                                    <td>
                                        <h3>Rätta dina uppgifter</h3>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr height="40px">
                                    <td>
                                        <a href=""><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/watch.png" style="height: auto; width: 100%;"></a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr height="60px">               
                                    <td>
                                        Det är viktigt att vi har rätt uppgifter om dig. Logga in och ändra här.
                                    </td>

                                </tr>

                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td width="2%">
                        </td>
                        <td style="background-color: #ffffff;" width="32%">
                              <table>

                                <tr height="10px" style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;">
                                    <td>
                                        <h3>Tipsa oss om</br> ny medlem</h3>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr height="40px">
                                    <td>
                                        <a href=""><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/watch.png" style="height: auto; width: 100%;"></a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr height="60px"> 

                                    <td>
                                        Vet du någon som ännu inte är medlem? Tipsa oss! </td>

                                </tr>


                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td width="2%">
                        </td>
                        <td style="background-color: #ffffff;" width="32%">
                            <table>

                                <tr height="10px" style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;">
                                    <td>
                                        <h3>Utvecklas </br>som chef</h3>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr height="40px">
                                    <td>
                                        <a href=""><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/watch.png" style="height: auto; width: 100%;"></a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr height="60px"> 

                                    <td >
                                         Ta del av ett stort utbud av kostnadsfria kurser och seminarier! </td>

                                </tr>


                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>

        </tr>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30px"></td>
</tr>


    </table>
```

Comment: `<table>` elements stopped being considered "acceptable" for layout 20 years ago. Considering today's web programming landscape, using them for this purpose tells your potential clients: *"This guy doesn't know the basics about web technologies"* or, alternatively, it tells your potential boss: *"Fire this guy. Now!"*.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu You have a point. I am not a front-end person. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, by the way, isn't the use of tables in email templates still relevant?

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu is wrong. Tables are the only reliable way to work with all email clients. Email development is NOT web development.

Comment: @gwally I didn't notice the `html-email` tag. However, you're wrong about it being *"the only reliable way"*. If it were, Gmail would use it when auto-styling copy/pasted markup in email body. Yet, it doesn't. It uses `<div>`s.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, Email clients like Outlook do not work consistently with `div`. If it did, I would not be creating fancy tables to send out pretty emails. Once again, email development is not web development. I understand many of the principals I use are outdated in the web dev world, but since Outlook, Gmail and other email clients do not follow any standard, it's not likely they will grow up and suddenly work well with other clients. Outlook is worse than IE 6, IE 8. Worse yet, there's still a huge installed base of Outlook 2002 out there.

Comment: Why are you using three nested tables, when one table should suffice? Quite apart from the issues of using layout tables (though I appreciate html email is a hideous unwanted spawn of web development in general).

Comment: @gwally, the only thing which makes sense to me from what you're saying is "email development is not web development". I've been explaining it to clients for the past 10 years. Regarding the rest, I suggest an exercise: copy/paste whatever you want from the web into a gmail account and press send. View it in Outlook. Let me know how it renders and if it contains any tables. Happy coding!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu if you send from Gmail, you're stuck with the limitations of Gmail. Meaning, if Gmail does not like a css value or html value, it will strip it out.

Comment: True. But what's not stripped is pretty "safe". It's easily testable and works like a charm. Transforms days of coding into 20-30 minutes, especially if you have some experience. With results, in terms of compatibility, above most of the "payed" solutions. And, it's not about sending "from" Gmail, but "through" it, **once**, so the markup gets parsed. You can send it from whatever server you like from that point on. It will be rendered the same in most, if not all web clients (supporting html, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

Add valign="top" to the table cells themselves.

```
<td valign="top">
   <h3>Rätta dina uppgifter</h3>
</td>
```

Comment: That would only work if the rows wrap equally, which is never the case, cross-device. The only way this works is to have a single table with "empty" columns, which is... "so 80's" it's almost cool.

Comment: On all table cells you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're adding a height to `tr`.

Start with a basic table structure and add in the components you need. You would almost be better off creating a table for your title and a table for your table images. You'll find more consistent results with a structure like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>*title table*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>*three table*</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The parent table will control the width align all of the other tables in one column.

If you want the images to be the same width, add `max-width:value;` to each image. Try a table format like this:

```
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="600">
<tr>
    <td width="33%" valign="top" align="center">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/watch.png" style="height: auto; max-width: 100px; display: block;">
        </a>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </td>
    <td width="33%" valign="top" align="center">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/watch.png" style="height: auto; max-width: 100px; display: block;">
        </a>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </td>
    <td width="33%" valign="top" align="center">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/watch.png" style="height: auto; max-width: 100px; display: block;">
        </a>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

If you're trying to do responsive email development and wish to see the table cells stack, I suggest looking up a responsive email template and following that instead. This sample will get your three column table working consistently.

Good luck.

Comment: In the second snippet, the table does not adjust to the screen size even though the alignment it kept.

Comment: @Disasterkid As I said before, if you're trying to create a responsive email, try downloading a template that does what you want and study how it works. The table you posted was never going to work consistently.